# Differentiating between input ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently creating an application which consists of *multiple* HTML ranges.

```
<input id="r1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="50" onChange="showValue(this.value)" />
```

On value change, the following function is called:

```
function showValue(newValue) 
{
    if (newValue == 100) 
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = "Calm";
        mood = "Calm"; 
        resetContent(); 
        getContent(mood);  
    } 
    else if (newValue == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = "Agitated"; 
        resetContent();
        mood = "Agitated"; 
        getContent(mood); 
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = ""; 
        resetContent(); 
    }
}
```

`getContent` takes in the mood as a parameter and searches through an xml file and returns all results which match the mood:

```
function getContent(mood) {
    $(xmlDoc).find("program").each(function(){
            // this is where all the reading and writing will happe
            if ($(this).find('mood').text() == mood) {
            $("#content").append(
                '<p>Name: ' + $(this).find('name').text() + 
                '<br> Mood: ' + $(this).find('mood').text() + 
                '</p>'
                );
            }
        });
}
```

My aim is to create an aditional 3 ranges which hold different moods. How would I go about handling the different ranges within the `showValue` function so they all work independantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array in javascript to hold the mood's value

```
    var moods=[["Agitated","Calm"],["sad","happy"],["angry","smiling"]];
    function showValue(newValue,id) {
    if (newValue == 100) 
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = moods[id][1];
        mood = moods[id][1]; 
        resetContent(); 
        getContent(mood);  
    } 
    else if (newValue == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = moods[id][0]; 
        resetContent();
        mood = moods[id][0]; 
        getContent(mood); 
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = ""; 
        resetContent(); 
    }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9y1foc5s/

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise let me know what you were looking for.

Comment: It's a perfect solution. Thank you. As a side question; Do you know how I can reset all other sliders back to value 50 when another slider is changed?

Comment: Yes you can easily do that, check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/p37oysoL/ let me know if you don't understand the code

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is make all the input use the same function but perform different actions basing on some of their attributes, in this case `id`:

```
function doIt($elem) {
    if ($elem.attr('id') == 'r1') {
        $("#output").html('action1' + $elem.val());
    }
    else if ($elem.attr('id') == 'r2') {
        $("#output").html('action2' + $elem.val());
    }
}

$('input').on('input', function(){
    doIt($(this));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xb51Lqnb/7/